# Slider/carousel dots not properly working for semi automatic carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm trying to do a slider/carousel. I have it set up with the dots underneath changing due to the user clicking on the left or right arrows. That works fine and the user can click a dot and change the slide that way too. However, when the image automatically changes, all the dots below are 'blank.'

Here's the script:

```
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();

    var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
      showSlides(slideIndex = n);

    }

    function showSlides(n) {
      var i;
      var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
      if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
          slides[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }

      slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    }

    function carousel() {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dots");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           x[i].style.display = "none";  
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
          dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }

        myIndex++;
        if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
        x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        setTimeout(carousel, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
    }
```

And here's some HTML

```
        <div id="slider_dots">
            <span class="dots" onClick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
            <span class="dots" onClick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
            <span class="dots" onClick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            <span class="dots" onClick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
        </div><!--dots-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to closely inspect the dot elements in Chrome to be certain that it's not something related to the CSS.

Personally, I've always found the removal of classes problematic using vanilla javascript.  Fortunately, jQuery greatly simplifies it.

Here's an almost identical script that I regularly use ...

```
    var slide = document.querySelectorAll("side nav ul");   // Identify each page to cycle through.
    var dots  = document.getElementsByClassName('dot');     // Identify each dot generated within #pagination.
    var slideIndex = 1;
    var slideViewing = false;


// Dynamically creates dots based on length of slides.
    for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
        $('#pagination').append("<a class='dot' rel='"+[i]+"'>" + [i] + "</a>" );
    }

    slider(slideIndex);


// Next/previous controls
    function slideChange(n) {
        slider(slideIndex += n);
        slideViewing = true;
    }


// Manual Transition (using arrow keys)
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) {
            slideChange(-1);
        }
        if(e.keyCode == 39) {
            slideChange(1);
        }
    });


    function slider(n) {
        if (n > slide.length) { 
            slideIndex = 1; 
        } 
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slide.length;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
            slide[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            $(dots[i]).removeClass('active');
        }

    // Style active slide and dot.
        slide[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        $(dots[slideIndex - 1]).addClass('active');

    // Loop (for auto transition)
        setTimeout(slider, 14000);
    }
```

This causes the dots (equal to the number of slides) to automatically be inserted into ...

```
<div id="pagination"></div>
```